# In 1 Corinthians 4:5 is the usage of κρίνω (G2919) the same as in Corinthians 5:3?

Tags: word-study, 1-corinthians

1 Corithians 4:5 (NKJV)

> 5 Therefore **judge** (*κρίνετε*) nothing before the time, until  the Lord comes, who will both bring to light the hidden things of  darkness and reveal the counsels of the hearts. Then each one’s praise  will come from God.  Fools for Christ’s Sake

1 Corinthians 5:3 (NKJV)

> 3 For I indeed, as absent in body but present in  spirit, have already **judged** (*κέκρικα*) (as though I were present) him who has so  done this deed.

If Pauls use of "judged" (determine, distinguish, condemn) in 1 Corithians 4:5 is in the same sense as in 1 Corinthians 5:3,I find it difficult to reconcile the 2 texts

Answer (score -1):

Here is my translation of 1 Corinthians 4:5.

[image]

And my translation of 1 Corinthians 5:3

[image]

### Conclusion

It is unreasonable to imagine Paul is instructing the church at Corinth to defer all judgment until Jesus comes, which is the sense one gets from reading the KJV. So, a different perspective on the text is appropriate.

I believe I have shown that Paul's use of "judgment" is entirely consistent in these verses. The problem comes from overly attributing to *καιροῦ* the idea of "the end of things", which one might be tempted to do because of the mention of Jesus' coming.